# 310 'Too many redirects' error that comes every few hours and resolves itself within a few minutes

Tags: iis, redirect, rewrite, https

Following some recent changes (see below), the URL https://mysite.tld works fine until every 3-6 hours, httpstatus.io starts reporting 11 redirects (it doesn't details those redirects however, it just says 'URL not functioning properly' or some such). It's always 11.

It resolves itself within 1-5 minutes, reporting 0 redirects again, or if I recycle the relevant app pool, or edit the web.config file in any way, it resolves the issue immediately.

Has anyone seen this or something like it before? How can I debug further?

Background

The issue started after installing a certificate from Let's Encrypt and moving the site from non-secure www to secure non-www on a unique IP. I also added a second certificate to the FTP server.

The response headers when it's working are:

```
Cache-control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma:no-cache
Content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-powered-by:PHP/5.6.2
X-pingback:https://mysite.tld/wordpress/xmlrpc.php
Link:https://mysite.tld/wp-json/; rel="https://api.w.org/", <https://mysite.tld/>; rel=shortlink
Set-cookie:PHPSESSID=8kshloboqs5gdh05ej026s5df3; path=/
Date:Fri, 30 Sep 2016 11:28:37 GMT
Connection:close
Content-length:54191
```

My web.config contains the following redirects:

```
<rule name="Redirect to non-www" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mysite\.tld$" negate="true" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://mysite.tld/{R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://mysite.tld/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

My wp-config.php file contains the following to negate any browser caching issues and I've disabled wp-super-cache:

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your URL HTTPS Rewrite.

Change the URL Rewrite rule to whats below and deploy it at the "Global Level" in IIS, so the rule is stored in the applicationhost.config. If you have multiple sites you'll need create a rule for each one and add another condition of each site.

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)" />
       <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^80$" />
       </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://mysite.tld/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

I know logically, it doesn't make any sense, I had the same issue. Through a lot of trial and error I was able to solve it this way. I feel your frustrations, others also have reported this issue before, but no resolutions were provided as you know or else you wouldn't be posing this question :)

If this answer is correct, please mark is as such.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. Why will changing the rule to target requests based on server-port rather that http_host help?  Is it at all related to this: https://forums.iis.net/t/1178961.aspx?Redirect+loop+bug

Comment: I'm the person that provided the solution on that thread "Rodrogue"

Answer (score 0):

We just went through this exercise and found that the problem was the checkbox for `Require Secure (HTTPS) sign in (You must have enabled SSL on IIS)` on the IIS server. Unchecking that solved the issue.

We are using the load balancer to redirect to HTTPS so it isn't needed on the server.  The "too many redirects" was because of the retries between the load balancer and the server so, yes, it was a redirection issue but not related to any scripts on the server.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!